# How to use Factory Class and attributes in Delphi Spring4D

Tags: delphi, dependency-injection, factory, spring4d

How to use attributes correctly to create different implementations for the `IDog` interface in the `IDogFactory` interface? Is it possible to create different implementations for one interface using Factory interface?

```
type
  IDog = interface
    function GetName: string;
    procedure Test;
  end;

  IDogFactory = interface(IInvokable)
    [TTola]
    function CreateTola: IDog;
    [TRudy]
    function CreateRudy: IDog;
  end;

  IFamillyDog = interface
    function Dogs: IList<IDog>;
    function Count: Integer;
  end;

  TTola = class(TInterfacedObject, IDog)
  public
    constructor Create;
    function GetName: string;
    procedure Test;
  end;

  TRudy = class(TInterfacedObject, IDog)
  public
    constructor Create;
    function GetName: string;
    procedure Test;
  end;

  TFamillyDog = class(TInterfacedObject, IFamillyDog)
  private
    fDogs: IList<IDog>;

    function Dogs: IList<IDog>;
    function Count: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create(aFactory: IDogFactory);
  end;

Tree:
 
  C.RegisterType<IDog, TTola>('Tola');
  C.RegisterType<IDog, TRudy>('Rudy');
  C.RegisterType<IFamillyDog, TFamillyDog>;
  C.RegisterType<IDogFactory>.AsFactory;
```

I tried to run the example code changing the details, I always get the error:

> No default found for type IDog

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is not supported.

I assume you are after a feature like [what Castle Windsor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md#get-methods-lookup-components-by-name) can do.
It looks like a nice feature and I will consider adding in the future.

For the time being you have to implement the factory yourself as an auto factory built by the container does not support this.